# WP8 get URI of images in MediaLibrary

Tags: windows-phone-8, uri, longlistselector, media-library

As I am using my own LongListSelector to let the user select from an image I need to retrieve the URI's of all images in the `Medialibrary`. I couldn't find any possibility to do this yet.

All I have seen what is possible is to get the name of the image:

```
MediaLibrary m = new MediaLibrary();

foreach (var r in m.Pictures)
{
    Stream imageStream = r.GetImage();
}
```

How can I get the rest of the path?

**EDIT**

Following the first solution:

*Gallery.xaml*

```
 <phone:LongListSelector 
                x:Name="GalleryLLS"
                LayoutMode="Grid" 
                GridCellSize="108,108"
                SelectionChanged="GalleryLLS_SelectionChanged"
                Margin="0,0,144,12"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfImages}" >
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Width="150" Height="150" 
                                Source="{Binding}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector>
```

Gallery.xaml.cs

```
    private List<WriteableBitmap> _listOfImages = new List<WriteableBitmap>();

    public List<WriteableBitmap> ListOfImages
    {
        get { return _listOfImages; }

        set { _listOfImages = value; }
    }

    public Gallery()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var ml = new MediaLibrary();
        var Pictures = ml.Pictures;
        foreach (var item in Pictures)
        {
            ListOfImages.Add(PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(item.GetImage()));
        }

    }
```

results in not showing images. Debugger shows that imageas are added correctly to my list but I won't see anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the API doesn't exposes URI property for pictures returned from Media Library. So you need to do it with different approach. For example, you can have a list of `WritableBitmap`s instead of list of URIs :

```
private List<WriteableBitmap> _listOfImages = new List<WriteableBitmap>();
public List<WriteableBitmap> ListOfImages
{
    get { return _listOfImages; }

    set { _listOfImages = value; }
}
.......
.......
var ml = new MediaLibrary();            
var Pictures = ml.Pictures;
foreach (var item in Pictures)
{
    ListOfImages.Add(PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(item.GetImage()));
}
........
//in XAML
<phone:LongListSelector ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfImages}"> 
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Width="150" Height="150" 
                                Source="{Binding}"/> 
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
........
</phone:LongListSelector>
........
```

[Codes adapted from [http://www.neelesh-vishwakarma.com](http://www.neelesh-vishwakarma.com/2013/07/getting-images-from-albums-in-windows.html#.Uw3WtYU4T_g)]

Comment: It seems the decoding is working fine but nothing is shown in my list. I will update my question according to your answer

Comment: It seems that UI not updated as ListOfImages property populated. To solve that, try to either : 1.change `List<WriteableBitmap>` to `ObservableCollection<WriteableBitmap>` or 2. put `InitializeComponent();` after `foreach` block.

Comment: Tried both(together as well), no result

Comment: databinding as used in this part : `ItemsSource={Binding ListOfImages}` needs DataContext. Try to add `this.DataContext = this;` in constructor (somewhere after `InitializeComponents();` line), in addition to my previous suggestion.

Comment: I now need to store the selected picture into IsolatedStorage. How could i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need the path? To show the image? If you just need to show the image in the list as a thumbnail, you can use the stream to create a `BitmapImage`:

```
var bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.SetSource(r.GetThumbnail());
```

Now you can set that `bi` as a `Image.Source`.

Comment: Yes I would like to show it in my LongListSelector. See my edited question. As I want to let the user edit the picture in another page i first wanted to pass the path as a string. But I guess I will have to save the image to the isolated storage anyway

Comment: In your view model you can keep both `BitmapImage` and path to the image. And you pass that path to the edit page. Also, don't use `GetImage`, use `GetThumbail` instead http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434150.aspx.